# How to obtain Battery Stats in Android at runtime?

Tags: android, power-management

I want to display Battery level stats in my app. How can we obtain such information like Battery Power, Battery Voltage, etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Battery in SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
            int level = -1;
            if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale; /* This is your battery level */ 
            }
         }
    };
    IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
}
```

or check out this guy (who wrote the code I posted): http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html

Answer (score 3):

Is [this](http://almondmendoza.com/2009/01/04/getting-battery-information-on-android/) of any help?

```
public class Main extends Activity {
   private TextView contentTxt;
   private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
         contentTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
      }
   };

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      contentTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.monospaceTxt);
      this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
         new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
   }
}
```

Also, see [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/BatteryInfo.java;h=ef60fc35b1f0f80f9bb88cc9d4fc5eaf55e9ef4b;hb=de2d9f5f109265873196f1615e1f3546b114aaa7).