# Retrieving configuration of my android device programmatically

Tags: android

Can anyone explain me that how can i get the configuration of Android device programatically in my app.
Also how can I get the other device related information like **Battery usage,CPU load,RAM usage,Memory details** etc programatically.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you started for the battery:
[Android Battery in SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk)

And this will get you a bunch of system properties (look at the getProperty method):
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html

Also these threads on memory management will provide a place to start:
[Get Memory Usage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android)

[How to get current memory usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)

Comment: thanks koopaking3, for your reply. Can you also tell me that how can get the details of app installed in my device .

Comment: Details of your app or some other app on the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use package Manager, using package manager you can get it