# Android Development: Show Battery Level

Tags: android, power-management

I've been searching for this and only find really messed up things.
Isn't there a easy way to show the battery level like 21% on a toast or Textview?
Or how can i achieve this?

//Simon

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Battery in SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk)

Comment: If you want to read it from the file system you can get that from /sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity which by default is 50.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you mean changing the battery status on the emulator do the following. Connect to the emulator via telnet and change the status and capacity

```
> telnet localhost 5554
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
power ac off
OK
power discharging
OK
power capacity 21
OK
exit
>
```

Ahh, well you can do what it says on the page Ted mentioned, and then use a handler to show a toast. This is the code you need to add to your activity.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler;

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
        Log.i(TAG, "level: " + level + "; scale: " + scale);
        int percent = (level*100)/scale;

        final String text = String.valueOf(percent) + "%";
        handler.post( new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, i mean like BatteyManager.getLevel() but there isnt. so basicly just show how much battery procentage i have on my phone

Comment: @Augusto: Ideally, use `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` instead of `"level"`. Also, the level is not a percentage. It is a value ranging from 0 to the value of the `BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE` extra. On many devices, the scale *is* 100, but do not assume that.

Comment: Don't forget to register the receiver:
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
:)

Answer (score 14):

To get the battery level right now, call:

```
registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

(note: typing that in from memory, please adjust if needed)

This will return an `Intent` with various extras documented on the `BatteryManager` class. Use `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` and `BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE` to determine the percentage remaining.

If you need to know over a period of time as the battery changes, use the `BroadcastReceiver` approach @Augusto outlined in his answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
    public static String batteryLevel(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent  = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));   
        int    level   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int    scale   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
        int    percent = (level*100)/scale;
        return String.valueOf(percent) + "%";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
private void batteryLevel() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                batterLevel.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination like that:

```
 BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager) getActivity().getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
 int batLevel = 100;
 int level;
 int scale;
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      batLevel = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
 }
 if(batLevel == 0){
     Intent intent  = getActivity().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
     level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
     scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
     batLevel = (level*100)/scale;
}
```

I did it like that because on a Nexus 5 device with Marshmallow "batLevel" returned 0 always. That solved it completely!

Good luck