# How to get the capacity of the battery in code

Tags: android, power-management

I am trying to read the capacity of the battery in code, but so far I haven't succeeded.  Does anyone know how to read the battery capacity programmatically?

I need a code snippet or some reference as to where to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk). You use the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent to get the information. You would use the [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) to get the constants. I believe that constant that you would be looking for is `EXTRA_SCALE`

Comment: I looked in the documentation and it says very little about what the extra_scale returns, it says "Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer containing the maximum battery level." What is the unit of measurement ? Does this extra_scale value have some boundary ?

Comment: for scale I get value 100, I guess this is the maximum value that level can reach, it meas the level is measured in "%".

Comment: I'm not sure either. The documentation is very vague, as you said. You should do some testing to find out. Print the value into logcat.

Comment: Ah yes, that is probably what that is. What unit are you actually looking for? `EXTRA_VOLTAGE` gives you voltage, but as far as I can tell there's no other measure of capacity available.

Comment: well, the capacity of my battery is 1200mA h. But I guess this is not possible to be read. :(