# Measure a battery level of Android devices

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way to measure power (battery level) of an Android device. I can see applications doing something with a battery level of an Android device so I was wondering how I can get the battery level from Android APIs.

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) is the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Check out the [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) class of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There's a broadcast receiver that tell you when the battery level changes. See this thread for code: [Android Battery in SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk)