# Android disable display off while charging

Tags: java, android, battery, power-management

In my application I need to disable display power off when device is charging. There is an option in Developer Menu to disable it, so I can to send Intent for user to enable it.

Also I've found info about PowerManager and WakeLocks, but it is for Alarms, I think. And I must to handle, is device charging.

What is the better, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk) and then [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've do this by that code:

```
final boolean isStayAwake = isStayAwakeEnabled(context);

if (!isStayAwake) {
    intent = new Intent(ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
}

context.startActivity(intent);
```

There user must check 'stay awake' option

I've used my own ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS constant because of problems with default one, which have not "com." prefix

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to try [`FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) from the [`WindowManager.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But even in your solution I must handle, is device power connected