# What are the units for battery voltage?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, power-management

I retrieved battery temperature and voltage information using the intent Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED and the values I got are pretty weird. I could not get any clue: temperature=270 and voltage=3782!

What are these values? Do they have any units like celsius, fahrenheit or milli or micro volt?

Comment: It's 3.782 volts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097828/102937

Comment: 3.782 Volts = 3782 mV (milli-volts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
voltage- int, current battery voltage in millivolts

temperature - int, current battery temperature in tenths of a degree Centigrade
```

http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/server/BatteryService.java.html

you can get detailed information from above link