# Android Battery temperature correct data

Tags: android

```
intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
```

I have this code, returning: 285, 292, 300 etc

What is this magic number? How can it be convert to Celsius?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to divide that by 10, meaning 285 would be 28.5 °C, 292 -> 29.2 °C and 300 ->  30.0 °C

Answer (score 7):

`voltage`- int, current battery voltage in millivolts

`temperature` - int, current battery temperature in tenths of a degree Centigrade

[Here is the source file](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java;l=106)

Answer (score 1):

The values are 28.5 , 29.2 and 30.0 degree Celsius

value = value/10

[Android Battery in SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk)