# Get battery voltage

Tags: android

Is there a way I can make a system call to get the actual battery voltage in Android?
I wish do to something like this:

```
double voltage = getVoltage();
//run code
double newVoltage = getVoltage();
```

Thanks

EDIT - Working code:

```
fun getVoltage(context: Context): Int {
    val intent = context.registerReceiver(null, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
    return intent?.getIntExtra(android.os.BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1) ?: -1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the usage of BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE within a BroadcastReceiver class in this response: [Android Battery in SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805895/android-battery-in-sdk/5097828#5097828)

Answer (score 0):

Android has a BatteryManager class that allows you to get information about battery usage.  There's a constant EXTRA_VOLTAGE that may be what you are looking for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html